# Functional Programming Book (O'reilly): Mutable List Example: True or False

Tags: java, list, immutability, mutable

I am reading the Book O'reilly Functional Programming for Java Developers from Dean Wampler.

On the page 9, It uses an example titled:

"**Consider the following example, where a mutable List is used to hold a customer's orders**:

```
public class Customer {

//No setter method

private final List <Order> orders;

public List <Order> getOrders() {return orders;}

public Customer (...) {...}
```

Ok.

1. according to the book, **if I assign final** to a List it means that it will not mutate because it prevents the reassignment  of its value.
2. What its the meaning of **(...)** & **{...}**

Thank you very much for the explanation in advance.

Comment: Is there a question in #1? As for #2, the dots just mean that the Customer constructor has some unspecified arguments and some unspecified body.

Comment: 1: What's the question? 2: They're used as examples; think of it as a cleaner way to say "blah blah blah, this part doesn't matter, since the important part is up above"

Answer (score 3):

your interpreation is wrong or the book made a mistake:

this

```
private final List <Order> orders =....;
```

means only that you can not change that reference like doing somewhere later

```
orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

but the list can for sure mutate since you can put, remove and truncate its content

Comment: to clarify ,only the `final` has the meaning explained. the private has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

`according to the book, if I assign final to a List it means that it will not mutate because it prevents the reassignment of its value.`

Yes 'private final' means you cant change the value. 
Which mean you need to re-create it on change. 
This makes the class immutable by using a mutable data structure.

Edit: to clarify, the list is mutable. The class is immutable, because the list is private and final and there is no setter. Which makes the list read only.

`What its the meaning of (...) & {...}`

Three dots usually  represent a code that is irrelevant to the example.

The code us an example of Costumer construction.

In this case `(...)` Is the function signature arguments (which mean that there are ones, but it doesn't matter for the example.

`{...}` represent the function body, Which again, irrelevant to the example.